# Why does the melting point of hexafluorosilicic acid differ that much in these two solution concentrations?

Tags: solutions, melting-point

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluorosilicic_acid) article for hexafluorosilicic acid:

> Melting point:
>
> ca. 19 °C (66 °F; 292 K) (60–70% solution)
>
> $<$ −30 °C (−22 °F; 243 K) (35% solution)

What's the reason for this huge difference in melting point while the solution concentration differs by about 30%?

Comment: if you compare it to e.g. the phase diagram of water - sulfuric acid, it is not a huge difference at all.

Comment: Yeah, it's nothing special. One could say something like (H3O)2SiF6 is essentially a compound that melts, not a solid solution.